# How to count multiple numerical variables in a column in R without installing a package?

Tags: r, variables

I'd like to count the number of recurring numerical variables in a given column.
My data set is: mydata

And I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
mydata <- structure(list(VARIABLE = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4)), 
  .Names = "VARIABLE",   row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

mydata
##     VARIABLE
## 1        1
## 2        1
## 3        2
## 4        3
## 5        3
## 6        3
## 7        4
## 8        4
```

I'd like to calculate the number of 1s,2s,3s,4s in column `VARIABLE` (Two 1, One 2, Three 3, Two 4). Is there anyway I can do this without installing an additional package?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find that you get better answers if you take the time to make your question reproducible. Please follow the guidelines (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), paying special attention to the part about `dput()`. Thanks!

Comment: okay! thank you!! I'll learn how to ask question in a proper format!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `table` as follows, it comes from the `base` package:

```
mydata <- data.frame(VARIABLE = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4))
table(mydata$VARIABLE)

# 1 2 3 4 
# 2 1 3 2
```

As suggested by Maiasaura, you can turn the output into a nice data.frame:

```
data.frame(table(mydata$VARIABLE))
#   Var1 Freq
# 1    1    2
# 2    2    1
# 3    3    3
# 4    4    2
```

Comment: `data.frame(table(VARIABLE))` would result in nicer formatting.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `?table` you could also use `?rle` in the instance of wanting to detect "runs" of particular repeating values in a variable/vector. In this instance, you will get the same results as using the `table` function, though this is not always the case.

```
mydata <- data.frame(VARIABLE = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4))
rle(mydata$VARIABLE)
```

Result:

```
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 2 1 3 2
  values : num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
```

You can subset the results of the `rle` function as well, like so:

```
rle(mydata$VARIABLE)$values
[1] 1 2 3 4

rle(mydata$VARIABLE)$lengths
[1] 2 1 3 2
```

Comment: You can create a `data.frame` from the results by `do.call(data.frame,rle(mydata$VARIABLE))`